# CodenameOne Connection Request wait postResponse

Tags: java, rest, codenameone

i've done a rest web service that gives me some contact information like numbers, age ... i get all this information in this function

```
public static void getRest(String search) {
    if(search.equals("")){
         json="http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.jersey.first/rest/jsonServices/print/";
    } else {
         json="http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.jersey.first/rest/jsonServices/print/"+search;
    }

    ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest() {

        @Override
        protected void postResponse() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
            Map<String, Object> h = p.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
            ArrayList object=new ArrayList();

            for (Entry<String, Object> entry : h.entrySet()) {
                object = (ArrayList) entry.getValue();

                int i=object.size();        
            }

            for(int i=0; i<object.size();i++){
                LinkedHashMap s= (LinkedHashMap) object.get(i);
                Risultati.add(s);
            }
        }
    };

    req.setUrl(json);
    req.setPost(false);
    req.addRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    InfiniteProgress prog = new InfiniteProgress();
    Dialog dlg = prog.showInifiniteBlocking();
    req.setDisposeOnCompletion(dlg);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(req);
```

Risultati is an attribute of the class: `ArrayList<LinkedHashMap> Risultati;`

the problem is that when i call the function `getRest("")` in this way:

```
getRest("");
Label contatto=null;
for(int j=0;j<Risultati.size();j++){
    LinkedHashMap s=Risultati.get(j);
    String nome=(String) s.get("firstName");
    String cognome=(String) s.get("lastName");
    String numero =(String) s.get("numero");
    contatto=new Label(nome+" "+cognome+" "+numero);
}
hi.addComponent(contatto);
```

it turns that Risultati is null, if i comment the for cycle i notice that the inner function readResponse is executed after...i don't know what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is that you're calling `NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(req)`. According to [it's documentation](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/NetworkManager.html#addToQueue-com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest-), it will add a connection request (the one you've just created) to a queue. After the connection request is added to the queue, it returns, meaning the request may or may not have been executed by that time.

You have to options to deal with this. In my opinion, the best way would be to update the user interface *after* the request has completed, as described in [the "File System, Storage, Network & Parsing" chapter](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html#_network_manager_connection_request) of the CodeOne manual:

```
req.addResponseListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        NetworkEvent e = (NetworkEvent)ev;
        // ... process the response
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could replace the call to `addToQueue(req)` with `addToQueueAndWait(req)`. The latter method  waits until the request is processed in the queue. The downside of the latter approach is that your user interface may freeze while the request is being processed, because the UI thread is blocked on the network I/O.

Comment: Good answer. One nitpick though is that the last paragraph is inaccurate. addToQueueAndWait will block the UI thread "correctly" without blocking the UI thread (yes that's zen) see: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/callserially-the-edt-invokeandblock-part-1.html and http://www.codenameone.com/blog/callserially-the-edt-invokeandblock-part-2.html You do need to show something like infinite progress or something...